# How many combinations are possible in this question?

Tags: combinations

I was curious how many combinations are possible in this scenario:

- The characters allowed to make up the combination are so:

  - Letters `a-z` (lowercase only)
  - Numbers `0-9`
  - Underscores `_`
  - Periods `.`
- The combination is **4** digits
- The combination **cannot** end with a period (`.`)

*Just a side note, this can have repeating characters.*
I also appreciate it a lot if someone were to answer this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I had tried `38*37*4`, but I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $26+10+1+1=38$ possible characters. We want $4$ characters and the combination cannot end with a period so we have $38^3 \times 37$ possible combinations.